# Perform regex on list to create new list

Tags: python, regex, list

Practicing some regex stuff in python. I wanted to parse some command output from Linux using python 3. So the following code generates a list split by newlines.

```
import subprocess
import re

cmd = 'df -h'
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode('utf8')
ln = output.split('\n')
print (ln)
```

So far so good. Now I want to generate a new list using a regex to extract some of the output.

Running the command outside of python outputs:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           787M  9.5M  778M   2% /run
/dev/sda2       211G  9.5G  191G   5% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  3.6M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           787M   20K  787M   1% /run/user/131
tmpfs           787M   32K  787M   1% /run/user/0
```

So say I want to extract the last column where the string starts with /run/
to a new list using the regex '/run/.* So my code now looks like:

```
import subprocess
import re


cmd = 'df -h'
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).decode('utf8')
ln = output.split('\n')
r = re.compile('/run.*')
newlist = [filter(r.search, ln)]
print (newlist)
```

I would expect that to work (because im a terrible programmer) but it doesn't, is filter the right way to do this ?  can someone offer some advise please ?

Comment: `newlist = [filter(r.search, ln)]` --> `newlist = list(filter(r.search, ln))`

Comment: thanks for the fast response ! This has been driving me nuts for hours  !

Comment: Yep. Glad to help. Everything checked out. Just had a feeling this was the only issue.

Comment: to have the new list just contain the strings ['/run', 'run/lock', 'run/user/101', run/user/0] - does that just require me to improve the regex in my r.compile('/run.*') ?

Comment: Indeed, it would.

Comment: im struggling with that, do i need to create a new list to remove the unwanted parts ?

Comment: It's up to you, you can choose to if you want. The regex needs changing, that's all.

Comment: so i can still use r.search()  ? , again thanks for your help and patience

Comment: No problem. But yeah you can.

Comment: hmm i don't understand the logic because search uses my pattern (re.compile()) to populate the list

Comment: for example if i change re.compile('(?=% )') I would expect the r.search to perform a look ahead from those characters and return ['/run', 'run/lock', 'run/user/101', run/user/0], but Im not sure r.search does that ? any advise ?

Comment: Nothing like trying it out yourself. ;) Hint: It does that.

Comment: I have been believe me, I have this working by generating another list and some hacky .split() but im dying to know why i cant get the regex to work !

Comment: Open a new question?

Comment: sure, thanks again.